# Error to open activity when listview item is clicked in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to open activity when click on `listview` item

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent());
```

and this is class **ItemClickEvent**

```
class ItemClickEvent implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth not enable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

This is class **DetailItemActivity**:

```
public class DetailItemActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1, tv2,tv3,tv4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abcd);

}

}
```

I created `abcd.xml` but when I click on `listview` item, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding a Log or a toast to make sure that the code reaches the part where it should start activity.

Comment: did you declare this `DetailItemActivity` in your manifest.xml file

Comment: Oh. I forget declare DetailItemActivity in mainfest. I fixed it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add a receiving Intent in your DetailItemActivity Class:-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```